# package moveit_simple_grasps in kinetic

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone,

I have written a small plugin for ROS after this tutorial:

http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib/Tutorials/Writing%20and%20Using%20a%20Simple%20Plugin

Now I have already installed a lot of packages that I can do a simple catkin_make in the ws, but no I am getting this error:

```
    -- Could not find the required component 'moveit_simple_grasps'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):

      Could not find a package configuration file provided by
      "moveit_simple_grasps" with any of the following names: 

moveit_simple_graspsConfig.cmake
moveit_simple_grasps-config.cmake
```

Now I have already installed this package via apt:

```
 % sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-simple-grasping
```

but I am getting the same error as mentioned before.

I have only found the requested package for hydro and indigo... can someone tell my what package I should install to get my tutorial compiled?

Thx in advance! :-)
BL

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284448/package-moveit_simple_grasps-in-kinetic/) by [blightzyear](https://answers.ros.org/users/33213/blightzyear/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-03-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blightzyear](https://answers.ros.org/users/33213/blightzyear/) on 2018-03-12**:
Can nobody help me? ;-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Now I have already installed this package via apt:

> ```
>  % sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-simple-grasping
> ```

> but I am getting the same error as mentioned before.

The package you installed is probably not the correct one: note how the error message mentions `moveit_simple_grasps`, not `simple-grasping`.

The former may be found here: [moveit_simple_grasps](http://wiki.ros.org/moveit_simple_grasps).

The latter here: [simple_grasping](http://wiki.ros.org/simple_grasping).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blightzyear](https://answers.ros.org/users/33213/blightzyear/) on 2018-03-13**:
Thank you for the info! :-)